# $A$ is positive semidefinite, $A^{(−1)} = [a^{−1}_{i j} ]$ and, $A^{(−1)}$ be positive semidefinite.Why does $rank A = 1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Let $A = [a_{i j }]\in M_n$ be positive semidefinite and suppose that each of its entries is nonzero.

Consider  $A^{(−1)} = [a^{−1}_{i j} ]$, and $A^{(−1)}$ be
positive
semidefinite.

Why does $rank A = 1$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us prove by induction on $n$ that if $A \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ satisfies the hypothesis of the question then $\mathrm{rank}(A) = 1$.

If $A \in M_1(\mathbb{R})$, there is nothing to prove. If $A \in M_{2}(\mathbb{R})$, one can prove the claim by direct calculation using Sylvester's criterion. Assume the hypothesis holds for matrices of dimension $n - 1$ with $n > 2$ and let $A \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$. Denote by $B \circ C$ the [Hadamard Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)) of $B$ and $C$. Then, since $A$ and $A^{(-1)}$ are positive semidefinite, we have

$$ 0 = \det(\hat{I}_n) = \det(A \circ A^{(-1)}) \geq \det(A) \det(A^{(-1)}) \geq 0 $$

where $\hat{I}_n$ is the $n \times n$ matrix that has $1$ in all entries. Thus, either $\det(A) = 0$ or $\det(A^{(-1)}) = 0$.

If $\det(A) = 0$, consider an arbitrary **principal** square submatrix $M$ of $A$ of order $n-1$ (obtained by a row and the **corresponding** column). By Sylvester's criterion, $M$ is also positive semidefinite, with non-zero entries and the same goes for $M^{(-1)}$ (as it is a principal square submatrix of $A^{(-1)}$). By induction hypothesis, $\mathrm{rank}(M) = 1$ which implies in particular that all principal minors of $A$ of order $2 \leq j \leq n - 1$ are zero. Together with $\det(A) = 0$, we see that all principal minors of $A$ of order $j \geq 2$ are zero.

Now, if a diagonalizable matrix $A \in M_n(\mathbb{F})$ has all principal minors of order $j \geq k$ equal to zero then $\mathrm{rank}(A) < k$. Why? If $\chi_A(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i c_i x^{n-i}$ is the characteristic polynomial of $A$ then each $c_i$ is the sum of all principal minors of $A$ of size $i$. If all the minors of size equal or greater than $k$ vanish, then $c_n = \ldots = c_k = 0$ and so $x^{n-k+1}$ divides $\chi_A(x)$. Since $A$ is diagonalizable, we must have $\dim \ker A \geq n - k + 1$ or $\mathrm{rank}(A) < k$.

This shows that $\mathrm{rank}(A) < 2$ and clearly $\mathrm{rank}(A) \geq 1$ so $\mathrm{rank}(A) = 1$.

If, instead we have $\det(A^{(-1)}) = 0$, the same argument shows that $\mathrm{rank}(A^{(-1)}) = 1$ but this immediately implies that also $\mathrm{rank}(A) = 1$.

Comment: I might be too tired already but, considering the first paragraph, what exactly is the induction hypothesis and where is the proof of the induction step? (Note that the fact that some smaller principal submatrices are of rank one does not imply that the larger have too.) I also somewhat fail to see where the assumption that $A^{(-1)}$ is semidefinite is used.

Comment: The induction hypothesis is that if $M$ is positive semidefinite matrix of dimension less than $n$ that has non-zero entries and such that $M^{(-1)}$ is also positive semidefinite then $M$ has rank one. Sylvester's theorem guarantess that if $A$ satisfies the conditions of the question then all principal submatrices of $A$ also satisfy the conditions of the question. If for a symmetric matrix all smaller principal submatrices are of rank one, then the matrix itself is of rank one.

Comment: In fact, it is enough to require that all principal $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ submatrices of an $n \times n$ symmetric (or, more generally, diagonalizable) matrix $A$ are of rank one to deduce that $A$ has rank one.

Comment: OK it seems reasonable. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, I forgot to justify why the topmost minor $\det(A)$ is also zero. I'll edit the answer to take this into account.